# Set Background color to ConstraintLayout in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I want to set Background ConstraintLayout in Compose without any other view. Is it possible?

I want do something like this:

```
ConstraintLayout(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
       color = colorResource(id = R.color.my_color)
   )
```

or

```
var rootView = ConstraintLayout(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
   )
rootView.color = colorResource(id = R.color.my_color)
```

but I don't found anything like this((((

```
Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            ConstraintLayout()
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Compose, you can use modifiers to apply color to the background.
what you want; This is not possible at the moment

But you can achieve your desire in the following ways:

1- Using the background modifier

```
ConstraintLayout(
  modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxSize()
       .background(Color.Yellow)
) {
}
```

2 - Using the drawBehind modifier

```
ConstraintLayout(
  modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxSize()
       .drawBehind {
          drawRect(Color.Yellow)
       }
) {
}
```

But according to the explanations in this video, it is better to use lambda modifier to achieve better performance

https://youtu.be/EOQB8PTLkpY?t=610